# Adding participants to existing calls in Signal iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc

I have created an iOS app using signal private messenger [(Signal Messenger)](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS). The application supports one to one calls using WebRTC.
Now I have a requirement of adding participants to existing calls.

Is this possible using the existing framework? Or do I have to implement additional code on server/client to support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find https://github.com/googlecodelabs/webrtc-web/issues/72 discussion with possible way to adapt `WebRTC` to multiple connections, while in other issue using https://github.com/medooze/media-server is advised. Therefore WebRTC do not offers this feature easily implemented.

`Signal-iOS` and `Signal-Android` now have only feature requests for conference calls https://community.signalusers.org/t/conference-calls/870 and https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/issues/1804 
So you can either wait until Signal developers would release that or contribute on the project and deliver that feature.

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind adding participant in the current call is known as **renegotiation**.

In this peers exchange the session description packet again with each other and negotiate ice candidates.

In order to achieve this in the signal app, you first have to know the flow of single call and make custom messages to flow to renegotiate the same.